# Is it possble to link a comment to installed packages, so I know why I installed it?

Tags: package-management

I have some packages I can not remember the reason, why I installed them. It possible to annotate a package with a comment or something similar?

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the package itself - it would be a pretty big security hole if folks could arbitrarily change code inside a signed package. It would be a pretty big reliability hole if folks start arbitrarily editing their apt database

Comment: I keep a journal for this purpose. In plain text, in my /home. Easily searchable, but not 'linked' to the package. Very handy for keeping track of experiments, cleaning up before a release-upgrade, and making sure I'm backing up everything I need to backup. Think about your needs, and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No .. but you can make a file (or journal), where you write when you install special packages and why.

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of that being avialable anywhere. Besides most package managers already have a short description of the software avialable to look up.

However you could look into the dependencies of that package you have installed to see if it was just installed because of something else.

```
apt-cache rdepends packagename
```